# :Skrollr not working on Chrome

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, skrollr

I seem to be having a problem with Skrollr, or at least I think it's Skrollr that's causing the problem...

I'm using this code:

```
data-0="background-position:0px 0px;"
data-end="background-position:-3000px 0px;"
```

which is related to Skrollr, and for some reason it's working on IE and Firefox, but not on Chrome unless I inspect element first, which I find very strange.

Has anyone experienced a similar problem and do you have any suggestions on how it might be fixed?

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: sure, my test link is http://stuartgreen.me.uk/webfonts/stuartgreen thank you for any help.

Comment: Just posted my answer, give it a go and let us know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing that you need to do a refresh since I notice it works if I resize the browser.

Try this code:

```
setTimeout(function () {
skrollr.get().refresh();
}, 0);
```

You can change the timeout to 1000 if necessary to ensure everything loads.

See similar issue [on github](https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr/issues/614)

Comment: Thanks for your help, it worked when I set it to 1000 :-) I really appreciate your help and assistance!!

Comment: No problem!  If you wouldn't mind selecting this as the right answer to help future people that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

I am really making an extreme quess, but try something like this in your css:

```
body {
   -webkit-transform: translateZ(0);
    -moz-transform: translateZ(0);
    -ms-transform: translateZ(0);
    -o-transform: translateZ(0);
    transform: translateZ(0);
}
```

Comment: Hmm I've just given it a go but it didn't seem to make any difference, it's really very strange becaue I mean... it even works in IE... So why not Chrome. I'm so confused.